# Task monitoring with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, workflows

I want to monitor batch jobs which get triggered by an REST API. This batch jobs are long running native data processings. So naturally, I want to return immediately after a REST call e.g. uploaded some data, and the long running job was started.

I have two usage scenarios for job monitoring in mind:
- An user of this API should be able to get the status of a job. So whether the task has finished, cancelled or is still running (ignoring progress for the moment)
- An administrator should have an overview of all currently running jobs, and ideally which REST API calls triggered the jobs

I was leaning towards Spring XD for this. But since my application is not really about big data, I wonder if there is a more lightweight solution for NodeJS.

What options do I have?

Comment: Your description is pretty vague, but why not set up a Redis store for this? Your batch job dispatcher (written in node.js) will have to write status information there.

Comment: I'm interested in this also. But ...  it is also a shopping question often discouraged on stack exchange.  Searching [npm](http://https://www.npmjs.com) for "task manager" suggests some possibilities.  The question might do better on "software recommendations" stack exchange, if that still exists....